# Koin's lifecycleScope vs activity.scope. Are they the same?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, koin, koin-scope

I'm learning Koin's Scope from https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/blob/master/koin-projects/docs/reference/koin-android/scope.md

If I have a Koin module as below

```
val myModule =
    module {
        scope<MyActivity> { scoped { Presenter() } }
    }
```

In my activity, I could do this

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val presenter by lazy {
        lifecycleScope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or I could use `this.scope` where `this` is `MyActivity` object.

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val presenter by lazy {
        this.scope.get<Presenter>(Presenter::class.java)
    }
    // ...
}
```

I tested they are the same. Are both the same, or different? If they are different, what are their differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the code I traced, the `lifecycleScope` will automatically close upon `ON_DESTROY`

So I trace from the `lifecycleScope` -> `getOrCreateAndroidScope()` -> `createAndBindAndroidScope` -> `bindScope(scope)` -> `lifecycle.addObserver(ScopeObserver(event, this, scope))`

The codes are all shown below.

```
val LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope: Scope
    get() = getOrCreateAndroidScope()
```

```
private fun LifecycleOwner.getOrCreateAndroidScope(): Scope {
    val scopeId = getScopeId()
    return getKoin().getScopeOrNull(scopeId) ?: createAndBindAndroidScope(scopeId, getScopeName())
}

private fun LifecycleOwner.createAndBindAndroidScope(scopeId: String, qualifier: Qualifier): Scope {
    val scope = getKoin().createScope(scopeId, qualifier, this)
    bindScope(scope)
    return scope
}
```

```
fun LifecycleOwner.bindScope(scope: Scope, event: Lifecycle.Event = Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
    lifecycle.addObserver(ScopeObserver(event, this, scope))
}
```

```
class ScopeObserver(val event: Lifecycle.Event, val target: Any, val scope: Scope) :
    LifecycleObserver, KoinComponent {

    /**
     * Handle ON_STOP to release Koin modules
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP) {
            scope.close()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle ON_DESTROY to release Koin modules
     */
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
            scope.close()
        }
    }
}
```